# How to change the publish point archive storage path

Tags: iis, smooth-streaming

How to change the archive storage path of the publish point (IIS media services)?

By default the video stores in  inetpub >> media >> archives >> ........

I want to change it to some other location on the network not within the same computer.

Thanks

Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to change the archive path. 
The first method is global for all publishing points :

- Run the IIS Manager;
- Select the first node on the left panel;
- Select Live Smooth Streaming in the features view;
- Change the archive path settings.

The second method is for one specific publishing point :

- Open the publishing point file (.isml) that you want change the archive path with your favorite text editor;
- Add this line between head attribute : 

   <meta name="archivePath" content="\\path\to\archive" />

The second method is useful when you create a publishing point from a script and not from IIS Media Service.
By default, the archive path property contained in file override the IIS Media Service archive path configuration.

Answer (score 0):

vincex86 is right without one point. I had a problem after changing archivePath. Don't forget to give "Write" permission to IIS_IUSRS user on specified folder